# Cannot create redirect where original url contains %20

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7, redirect

I've been researching the issue for hours and can't seem to find a working solution to this problem. I've created a redirect from `/sites/default/files/OLB%20Registration%20Guide.pdf` to `/sites/default/files/downl_section/Online-Banking-Registration-Guide.pdf` that doesn't work.

Here is the line in `.htaccess`

`Redirect 301 "/sites/default/files/OLB Registration Guide.pdf" /sites/default/files/downl_section/Online-Banking-Registration-Guide.pdf`

My first inclination was to remove `%20`, but still nothing... Does anyone have any insight as to how to create a redirect where the original url contains `%20`?

Thanks!

`.htaccess`

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig\.save)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Etags
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)(\.gz)?$">
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>

# Jan 10 2018
Redirect 301 /cards https://company.org/login?utm_campaign=creditcard-mastercard&utm_source=directmail

# feb 09
Redirect 301 /bgvisa /BGMasterCard

# jan 2015
Redirect 301 /qchoice /checking

# july 1
Redirect 301 /mobileapps /anywherebanking#tab-1

# pdfs
Redirect 301 "/5001-01-NEWcompany/UserFiles/file/Quicken and MS Money Resource Document.pdf" /sites/default/files/files/Quicken.pdf
Redirect 301 "/5001-01-NEWcompany/UserFiles/file/membership app_Minor_cp.pdf" /sites/default/files/files/custodial_app.pdf
Redirect 301 "/UserFiles/File/ONLINE DEPOSITS FAQ_NEW.pdf" /sites/default/files/files/ONLINE%20DEPOSITS%20FAQ_NEW.pdf

...more redirects...

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
  php_flag register_globals                 off
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
  RewriteRule (.*) https://www.company.org/$1 [R,L]

  # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
  # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
  # you don't bounce between http and https.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

  # rewrite documents path

        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =v=36d38d70-92ae-47e4-97a9-569a741557c4
        RewriteRule ^default\.aspx$ /why-company/careers/? [L,R=301]

        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =v=ae2715bb-8e70-4e7f-9b47-1607a62b9db4
        RewriteRule ^default\.aspx$ /contact-us/? [L,R=301]

        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =v=69940420-9499-452d-ba52-f40d6f03bcfb
        RewriteRule ^default\.aspx$ /why-company/recent-events/? [L,R=301]

        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =v=9ceaa473-41e1-49e2-8db8-a4a907b8f18e
        RewriteRule ^default\.aspx$ /services/atmbranchlocator/? [L,R=301]

        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =v=95d869d3-f576-4c1d-a467-b46ea9691c97
        RewriteRule ^default\.aspx$ /sites/default/files/files/QFCU_2012_Annual_Report.pdf? [L,R=301]

... more rewritecond / rewriterules...

RewriteRule ^sweepstakesrules?$ "/sites/default/files/files/MasterCard/Official Rules.pdf" [L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^March2014?$ /sites/default/files/files/March2014.pdf [L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^browsersupport?$ /sites/default/files/files/browsersupport.pdf [L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^QuickenInstructions?$ /sites/default/files/files/Quicken_conversioninstructions_Final.pdf [L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^servicedowntime?$ "/sites/default/files/downl_section/Service Downtime Chart.pdf" [L,NC]


  # Make sure Authorization HTTP header is available to PHP
  # even when running as CGI or FastCGI.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


  # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
  # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
  # downloaded.
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]


  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Just nothing happens? The directive you posted looks "OK". However, where are you seeing the source URL? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I've just noticed that you had previously edited the question from using `%2520` (which is a _doubly_ URL encoded space) to `%20` (which is simply a URL encoded space). The (now accepted) answer relates to your question _before_ the edit. Incidentally, if this was the case then you should have used `%20` (ie. a URL decoded `%2520`) in your initial `Redirect`, not a _space_, as you have shown in your example.

Comment: @MrWhite yes the initial question was a typo - thanks for following up though - I applied the method in your answer and made the appropriate changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mod-rewrite` for this redirection

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /sites/default/files/OLB%2520Registration%2520Guide\.pdf [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ /sites/default/files/downl_section/Online-Banking-Registration-Guide.pdf [L,R]
```

Comment: I'm sorry the site has gone down since. Probably a memory issue.. not related to your answer!

Comment: I removed my comments about the site breaking so future visitors won't think it was your answer, and added the `.htaccess` to my question if that makes things more clear

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
RedirectMatch 301 (/sites/default/files/)(OLB.*)(Registration)(.*)(Guide\.pdf)$ $1downl_section/Online-Banking-$3-$5
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test

Comment: I didn't originally, but now I did! What seems to be happening now is "/sites/default/files/downl_section/OLB%20Registration%20Guide.pdf" goes to "/sites/default/files/downl_section/OLB Registration Guide.pdf"

Comment: @JillianHoenig "OLB%20Registration%20Guide.pdf" and "OLB Registration Guide.pdf" are really the same thing. (This redirect is not triggering that - that may just be the way it's displayed in your browser?)

Comment: @MrWhite you're right that's just the way url's are displayed in firefox